# Ruby 1.8.7 Mac OS Bigsur __rvm_make -j8'

Tags: ruby, rvm

### Description

Get this issue when trying to install ruby 1.8.7 on Bigsur.

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/caio/.rvm/log/1635184861_ruby-1.8.7-p374/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

To proceed rvm requires a ruby-1.8.7-p374 compatible ruby is installed.
We attempted to install it automatically but it failed with status 2.
Please install it manually (or a compatible alternative) to proceed.
```

### Steps to reproduce

1. rvm install 1.8.7

[rvm_info](https://sharetext.me/c2yidbkd0c)
[make_log](https://sharetext.me/ph6la3fojc)

Comment: Hey Caio, what did you get after running `rvm info`?

Comment: Please add any logs directly to your Stack Overflow  question. As the external links have already expired, your question is not answerable in its current state.

Comment: try now ........

Answer (score 0):

If that first error is still showing:

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

You may need to install the command line tools, with something like this:

```
xcode-select --install
```

and then try again

Comment: xcode is already installed